# How can I do pip install or same thing similar in terminal for Jython to install packages

Tags: jython

I have just installed jython and want to install some packages like bs4 and mechanize in python I simply did **pip install** and done. How I can do the same thing for jython I tried **jip install package_name** but got an error. Please give the answer as simple as possible to follow thanks in advance.

Comment: "got an error". What error?

Comment: I used **jip install bs4** group, artifact, version = artifact_id.split(":")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack